# Matplotlib - different color for each hpoint

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib tutorial, they say

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

will plot points with same color.

In this case, how do I assign each point's color differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @HYRY mentioned you can use [`plt.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter). This 
takes an argument `c`  which is a *color or sequence of color*. This means you
can pass it any [color specification accepted by matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html)

So for example you could do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,4,9,16]
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'k']
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
plt.show()
```

Or a sequence of RGB color definitions

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,4,9,16]
colors = [[0.6, 0.3, 0.1], 
          [0.1, 0.6, 0.5],
          [0.1, 0.3, 1.0],
          [0.8, 1.0, 0.2]]

plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
plt.show()
```